# How to create and send a table by grouping rows by email addresses - GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets, datatable

I need help to create a table, from column [B] to column [I] if the emails from the managers of column [J] are the same:

[Example_01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UztJR.png)
The yellow lines have the same manager in column [J]: "rafalmfei@gmail.com", so I need to set up a single email with a table, for the manager (Column [J2] and [J3]) with a copy for o Partner E-mail "rafaalmeida_feitoa@yahoo.com.br" (column k [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i274u.png) and k [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIqCw.png)) with lines 2 and 3.

[Example_02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i274u.png)
And an email with another separate table for the manager "rafaalmeida_feitoa@yahoo.com.br", (column [4] and column [5]) with a copy for Partner E-mail "rafalmfei@gmail.com" (column k [4] and k [5]) with lines 4 and 5.

[Example_03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIqCw.png)
Currently, I have the email ready with the code below, but I receive the lines in separate emails, I need it to be in a single email in table format:

```
    function enviarEmailJornada(){
  // Linka a planilha de controle ao script e pega todas as colunas existentes
  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = planilha.getSheetByName("Analise_Maio");
  var linhas = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 156).getValues();
  var colunas;

  // Cria as variáveis necessárias para enviar o e-mail  
  var toEmail;
  var ccEmail;
  var subject = "[URGENTE] Análise imediata de projetos sem ETC";
  var message;


  // Percorre as linhas da tabela e busca os dados de cada coluna
  for(var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++){
    colunas = sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    toEmail = colunas[9];
    ccEmail = colunas[10];
    if(colunas[0] == "1"){
      message = "Caro(a), <br><br>";
      message += "Identificamos que os projetos abaixo apresentam ETC zero e estão em seu nome. <br><br>";
      message += "Adicionalmente, elencamos projetos que estão com ETC Zerado e que o valor faturado é inferior a 0% da última valorização do WIP, o que pode indicar um risco em relação à realização destes valores. <br><br>";
      message += "<br>————————————<br><br> " + " "+ colunas[1] +" " + colunas[2] + " " + colunas[3] + " " + colunas[4] + " "  + colunas[5] + " " + colunas[6] + " " + colunas[7] + " " + colunas[8] + " " +"<br><br><br>";
      message += "Peço a gentileza de que efetuem a imediata análise, reportando diretamente aos sócios dos projetos, a razão destas inconsistências. <br><br>";
      message += " Adicionalmente, como já diversas vezes solicitado, peço que efetuem imediatamente as baixas dos projetos cujo trabalho já foi concluído (ETC Zero) e valores faturados.<br><br>";
      message += "Conto com a sua pronta atuação. <br><br>";
      message += "Rafaela Feitosa <br><br>";
      GmailApp.sendEmail(toEmail,subject,"",{cc: ccEmail, htmlBody: message, name: "Análise imediata de projetos sem ETC"});
    }
  }  
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do the following**

- Retrieve all managers from the sheet
- Use `...new Set()` to retrieve unique values of managers
- For each distinct manager retrieve the relevant sheet values and push them into an html table
- Send an email after iterating through all rows and retrieving all data for particular manager

**SAMPLE**

```
function enviarEmailJornada(){
  // Linka a planilha de controle ao script e pega todas as colunas existentes
  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = planilha.getSheetByName("Analise_Maio");
  // Cria as variáveis necessárias para enviar o e-mail  
  var subject = "[URGENTE] Análise imediata de projetos sem ETC";
  var message;

  var colunas = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var managers =  sheet.getRange(1, 8, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  Logger.log(managers);
  var uniqueManagers = [...new Set(managers)];
  Logger.log(uniqueManagers);
  uniqueManagers.forEach(myFunction);

  function myFunction(manager) {
    var table = "<table>"
    var toEmail = "";
    var ccEmail = "";
    // Percorre as linhas da tabela e busca os dados de cada coluna
    for(var i = 0; i < colunas.length; i++){
      if(colunas[i][7] == manager && colunas[i][0] == "1"){
        toEmail = colunas[i][9];
        ccEmail = colunas[i][10];
        table += "<tr><td>"+ colunas[i][1] +"</td><td>" + colunas[i][2] + "</td><td>" + colunas[i][3] + "</td><td>" + colunas[i][4] + "</td><td>"  + colunas[i][5] + "</td><td>" + colunas[i][6] + "</td><td>" + colunas[i][7] + "</td><td>" + colunas[i][8] + " " +"</td></tr>";
      }
    }
    Logger.log("table"+ table);
    if(toEmail != ""){
      message = "Caro(a), <br><br>";
      message += "Identificamos que os projetos abaixo apresentam ETC zero e estão em seu nome. <br><br>";
      message += "Adicionalmente, elencamos projetos que estão com ETC Zerado e que o valor faturado é inferior a 0% da última valorização do WIP, o que pode indicar um risco em relação à realização destes valores. <br><br>";
      message += "<br>————————————<br><br> "
      message += table + "</table>";
      message += "<br><br><br>";
      message += "Peço a gentileza de que efetuem a imediata análise, reportando diretamente aos sócios dos projetos, a razão destas inconsistências. <br><br>";
      message += " Adicionalmente, como já diversas vezes solicitado, peço que efetuem imediatamente as baixas dos projetos cujo trabalho já foi concluído (ETC Zero) e valores faturados.<br><br>";
      message += "Conto com a sua pronta atuação. <br><br>";
      message += "Rafaela Feitosa <br><br>";
      GmailApp.sendEmail(toEmail,subject,"",{cc: ccEmail, htmlBody: message, name: "Análise imediata de projetos sem ETC"});
    }
  }
}
```

**References:**

- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)