# Google script change row color based on data change, sheet sorted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Link to demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OyXNOlGWlav3_MRsdUNi6U6APNbM-BYfyqzWWQAyUFM/edit?usp=sharing)

I have a sheet which is sorted by column E. Values in column E can be duplicate, which means that several rows can have the same value in column E.
Now I want to color rows which signify a change in column E.
Here's the code that I've built based on some great answers on StackOverflow:

```
function quicktest() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rangeData = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  //  var searchRange = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow-1, 5);
//  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  var previousclient = rangeData[2][5];
  console.log(previousclient);
  for ( j = 1 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){
    var currentclient = rangeData[j][5];
    console.log(previousclient," ",currentclient);
    if (previousclient != currentclient) {
      spreadsheet.getRange(j,1,1,5).setBackground("#cc4125");
      previousclient = currentclient;  
    }; 
}
```

The code runs, but the result is that it's "painting" the wrong cell and it's also not painting the entire row (columns A to H), it's painting just A to C.
I've also read some answers here that recommend sending the values to rangeValues, but that didn't work me. That's why it's listed as a comment in the code. Perhaps I do need to use it.
Here's how I'd like to demo sheet to look like after running this code:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Be careful with indices - arrays start with [0]

The respective confusion leads to several problems in your code:

- `rangeData[2][5]` means cell `F3` - not `E`, if you want to retrieve the column `E` - it corresponds to the array index `4` (both for previous and current client!)
- Given that the initial `previousclient` is not suposed to be colored (only the following onew) you should set it to the header row, so `rangeData[0][4]`
- When you use the method `getRange()` - the row indices start with `1` (unlike array elements!!!), so array element `i` corresponds to the row`i+1`

To fix those issue modify your code as following:

```
function change_row_color() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rangeData = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var previousclient = rangeData[0][4];
  console.log(previousclient);
  for ( j = 1 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){
    var currentclient = rangeData[j][4];
    console.log(previousclient," ",currentclient);
    if (previousclient != currentclient) {
      spreadsheet.getRange(j+1,1,1,5).setBackground("#cc4125");
      previousclient = currentclient;  
    };
  }}
```

UPDATE

Calls to external services including SpreadsheetApp methods [should be minimized](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services) because they make your code slower.

So, for example calling `setBackground` within each loop will result in a longer execution time.
If you want to set the colors only once with [setBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor) instead of `setBackground`, you can do it like this:

```
function change_row_color() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = spreadsheet.getDataRange();
  var rangeData = range.getValues();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var previousclient = rangeData[0][4];
  console.log(previousclient);
  var colors = [[0,0,0,0,0]];
  for ( j = 1 ; j < lastRow; j++){
    var currentclient = rangeData[j][4];
    console.log(previousclient," ",currentclient);
    if (previousclient != currentclient) {
      colors.push(["#cc4125","#cc4125","#cc4125","#cc4125","#cc4125"]);
      previousclient = currentclient;  
    } else{
      colors.push([0,0,0,0,0]);
    }
  }
range.setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```

Either this approach will be faster strongly depends on your data size and amount of duplicates.

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka! Workes like a charm now. However, the charm take quite some time to happen. Any ideas on how to make it run faster? Perhaps using the rangeValues idea which is set as a comment in my original code above?

Comment: `rangevalues` does exactly the same like `rangeData` (it gets a range) the only difference that instead of retrieving the whole data on the sheet it only retrieves the rows and columns you specify. If your sheet contains a lot of data but your function shall run only on part of it, it makes sense to deifne the range manually. But I believe you want to run the function on all data?

Comment: What you can do to speed up your code a bit is to replace `setBackground` within each iteration with [setBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor) that you call only once at the end of your code.

Comment: Yes. indeed I want to run in on the entire content of the sheet. I'm not sure I understand the setBackgrounds procedure. Can you please explain, or perhaps edit your answer with this new idea? I was thinking about using Cache. Will that help or am I completely off on it?

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. This new code is indeed quicker, but it still takes about 20s for a small test range of 350 rows. My actual range has close to 10K row so this code isn't a good idea during a workday. The issue is that we need to run this ad-hoc, and cannot afford nightly or other non-immediate runs.  Any ideas? Cache? BTW - the array I'm working on is an IMPORTRANGE array. Does this prolong the run time for this code?

Comment: Instead of updating previous client for each value, you can retrieve the unique rows with `...new Set()` as done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62130440/11599789) sample and color them. But this goes beyond the scope of you initial question and you should create new post to ask it.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62594719/13708028)