# Google Script/sheets - How to make a script run faster during a loop using ...new Set()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Based on the great support by @ziganotschka on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62590592/13708028), we have the following code. For each of reference, here's a [link to the demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OyXNOlGWlav3_MRsdUNi6U6APNbM-BYfyqzWWQAyUFM/edit?usp=sharing) posted on the original question.

```
function change_row_color() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = spreadsheet.getDataRange();
  var rangeData = range.getValues();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var previousclient = rangeData[0][4];
  console.log(previousclient);
  var colors = [[0,0,0,0,0]];
  for ( j = 1 ; j < lastRow; j++){
    var currentclient = rangeData[j][4];
    console.log(previousclient," ",currentclient);
    if (previousclient != currentclient) {
      colors.push(["#cc4125","#cc4125","#cc4125","#cc4125","#cc4125"]);
      previousclient = currentclient;  
    } else{
      colors.push([0,0,0,0,0]);
    }
  }
range.setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```

The script is running great, but it's running rather slow. My test array has 350 rows and it takes about 20s to run. My actual array has 10K+ rows, and growing. Once I run this code on the real array, I'd like to drop it to below 5s. ziganotschka suggested to use ...new Set(). I'd love you input on this.

Comment: The idea is that you study the other solution (and the references of the involved methods) and put some effort into integrating it into your code. Then you explain where you got stuck and need help.

Comment: The Loop part probably don't take that much time. Like it was explain in your previous question it is the "Calls to external services" wich take most of the time.

Comment: @user13708028 Why don't you use sheet contitional formating ?

Comment: @JulienMaret I would love to be able to use conditional formatting, or even the "subtotal feature" (not function) as we have in MS-Excel. This entire code is an awkward workaround to achieve a rather basic functionality: marking/splitting a table based on changes in a specific column. Any easier and more elegant solutions that you can think about shall be very highly appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: You can use conditional formatting: `=E2<>E1`; Apply to `E2:E`. How many rows need to be colored out of 350?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using Conditional formatting

To apply a given style for all the row where the value in the E column is the same as the previous row.

In your sheet:

- Format > Conditional formatting
- Apply to range `A2:Z`
- Format rule `Custom formula is`
- Value of formula `=$E2=$E1`   // change the value of E is you need to make the test on an other row.

Choose your wanted formatting style.

Comment: WOW! this is great, thanks! It worked perfectly, but actually it "marked" all the row below the first row with an identical value in column E. I wanted to mark only the first row so I changed the formula to "=$E2<>$E1". Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

May not be any faster but you can give it a try.

```
function change_row_color() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vs=rg.getValues();
  var colors=rg.getBackgrounds();
  colors.map(function(r){return r.fill('#000000')});//this is not necessary if the backgrounds always start as black.
  var pc=vs[0][4];
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(i>0 && r[4]!=pc) {
        colors[i].fill("#cc4125");
        pc=r[4];
    }
  });
rg.setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I'm getting this error: TypeError: Cannot find function fill in object #87cefa,#87cefa,#87cefa,#87cefa,#87cefa,#87cefa,#87cefa,#87cefa

Comment: @user13708028  The above code will not run on deprecated ES5 engine. To use the code, [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks. You're right. Indeed no error on V8 but runtime is actually slower on this version of the code. The code listed in my question is running faster. Any ideas for a more elegant/fast solution to mimic MS-Excel's "subtotal feature"(not function)?