# Problem with script that changes row color based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to replicate the answer to this question but with the data in different locations: [Google script change row color based on data change, sheet sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62590592/google-script-change-row-color-based-on-data-change-sheet-sorted)

Here is my much smaller sheet:

[image]

In this case, the "Orange" rows should be colored. However, my script below is not working because the variable "colors" does not seem to indicate the loop worked correctly. What is causing this?

```
function changeRowColor () {

const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
const lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow(); // 6
const range = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 2);
const rangeData = range.getValues(); // [[Apple, s], [Apple, s], [Orange, x], [Orange, s], [Banana, x], [Banana, r]]

let previousclient = rangeData[0][0]; // Apple
let colors = [[0, 0]];

  for (let i = 1 ; i < lastRow; i++){
    let currentclient = rangeData[i][0];

    if (previousclient != currentclient) {
      colors.push(["#cc4125","#cc4125"]);
      previousclient = currentclient;  
    } else {
      colors.push([0,0]);
    };
  };

Logger.log(colors);
range.setBackgrounds(colors);

};
```

Here is the result I am getting:

[image]

Here would be the desired result, where the rows alternate colors based on the value in column A:

[image]

Comment: Delete: `for (let i = 1 ; i < lastRow; i++){` Replace with: `for (let i = 0; i < lastRow; i++){` The referenced script started at 1 because they had a header row; you have no header. So your loop starts at 0.

Comment: A comment for future reference. Supplying your data as a image is OK when you're trying to show the expected result. But you need to supply the data in a table (or other accessible format) if you want as many users as possible to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your script, I think that the reason for `Here is the result I am getting:` is due to `previousclient = currentclient;`. In this case, `previousclient` is changed from "Apple" to "Orange". By this, at the next loop, "Orange" is compared with column "A". By this, your current result is obtained.

When this is reflected in your script, please remove the line of `previousclient = currentclient;`. But, in this case, the background color of rows except for "Apple" is changed.

If you want to set the background colors to only "Orange" row, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function changeRowColor() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  const range = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 2);

  // I modified the below script.
  const colors = range.getValues().map(([a]) => Array(2).fill(a == "Orange" ? "#cc4125" : null));
  range.setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```

- By this modification, the background color of only the row of "Orange"  is changed to `#cc4125`.

### Added:

From your following reply,

> My goal is not specifically to single out rows with "Orange" in column A. Rather, I would like for rows to alternate in colors and change once there is a change to the cell value in column A, that way it is easier to read

Your expected script might be the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
// Ref: https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/10/06/setting-alternate-background-colors-for-rows-in-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/
function changeRowColor() {
  const colors = { color1: "#cc4125", color2: "null" };
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const ranges = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues()
    .reduce((o, [b], i) => {
      if (b != o.temp) {
        o.temp = b;
        o.c++;
      }
      o[["color1", "color2"][o.c % 2]].push(`A${i + 1}:B${i + 1}`);
      return o;
    },
      { color1: [], color2: [], c: 0, temp: "" }
    );
  Object.entries(colors).forEach(([k, v]) => sheet.getRangeList(ranges[k]).setBackground(v));
}
```

Comment: Got it, thank you for taking the time. My goal is not specifically to single out rows with "Orange" in column A. Rather, I would like for rows to alternate in colors and change once there is a change to the cell value in column A, that way it is easier to read

Comment: @Alexa Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `My goal is not specifically to single out rows with "Orange" in column A. Rather, I would like for rows to alternate in colors and change once there is a change to the cell value in column A, that way it is easier to read `. Can you provide your expected result as an image?

Comment: I do apologize, I don't think I was explaining well! I basically want the row color to alternate based on the value in column A. Let me know if the desired result is clearer

Comment: @Alexa Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, now, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. This added script is from my blog. https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/10/06/setting-alternate-background-colors-for-rows-in-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/

Comment: @Alexa From your added image, when I saw your initial images, I thought that the 1st background color is no color. But, when I saw your added image, it seems that you wanted to use "#cc4125" at the 1st color. In that case, please modify `const colors = { color1: "#cc4125", color2: "null" };` to `const colors = { color2: "#cc4125", color1: "null" };`.